# accessing custom static html files in joomla

Tags: html, joomla1.5

I created some static html files (along with an index.html file) and put them within a "files" directory within the joomla parent directory. And I entered this address in the browser `http://mydomain/files` but it gives a 403 error. The current file permission on the 'files' directory is 755. How can I access the files on my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried accessing your files explicitly: `http://mydomain/files/youTestFile` ?